# Is there any method to solve this CSS margin issue?

Tags: html, css

The margin tag inside the `<style></style>` doesn't work! As you can see above the "user agent stylesheet", it shows that margin doesn't work.
I've tried finding missing characters, but I think there are none of them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="kr"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <link href="./Home-wonhui&#39;s first website._files/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <title>
        Home-wonhui's first website.
    </title>
     <meta name="description" content="this is my website" />
     
     <style> 
        div {
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: aquamarine;
        }
        body {
            margin: 10;
            background-color: wheat;
        }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>HELLO!!!!</div>
        <code>H i</code>
    </body>
</html>
```

+stylesheet is an empty file, which means nothing in there.
[image: Here]

Comment: aroundtheworld is right. You'll need to add `%` or `px` or one of several other units behind the number 10.

Comment: Honestly, while it may have been a silly mistake, this is just a ridiculous question that anybody with little to no amount of css knowlege should know. It applies to real life as well. You don't ask somebody to move by 10,  you ask them to move by 10 feet

Answer (score 5):

There is no unit defined for your margin. `10` is not a valid value.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin.asp

Comment: You're so helpful, i spend 3 hours to get throught this question. thank you!

Comment: No problem @Yourang. Please accept the answer as correct if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

**You are almost there!!!!**

You didn't specify any type of units to the margin that's why margin property is not applied.

Updated code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="kr"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <link href="./Home-wonhui&#39;s first website._files/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <title>
        Home-wonhui's first website.
    </title>
     <meta name="description" content="this is my website" />
     
     <style> 
        div {
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: aquamarine;
        }
        body {
            margin: 10px;
            background-color: wheat;
        }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>HELLO!!!!</div>
        <code>H i</code>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! i wasted 3 hours for this....